# VAR - Timeseries

Tags: time-series, regression, prediction, statsmodels, vector-auto-regression

I am building a timeseries prediction model using Vector Auto Regression Model. I am getting this error when I am trying to fit this model:

x contains one or more constant columns. Column(s) 14, 15 are constant. Adding a constant with trend='c' is not allowed.
I cannot drop these columns. So is there any other solution to overcome this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add trend='nc' in the model.fit() statement for VAR model.
Something like this:

```
model.fit(trend='nc')
```